# Display Directories and their files

Tags: coldfusion, cfdirectory

I am attempting to group the output of all directories in a specified path as well as the files within each respective directory.  Currently, I have:

```
    <cfset local.baseWebPath = ExpandPath( "./upload/views/files/" ) />
    <cfset custID = session.authUser.getuser_custid() />
    <cfset filters = "*.pdf|*.zip|*.doc*|*.ppt*|*.pps*|*.ai*|*.eps*|*.xls*|*.swf|*.rtf|*.psd|*.jpg|*.png|*.tif">

    <!---display directory for specific customer--->
        <cfdirectory 
            action = "list"
            directory = "#local.baseWebPath##left(custID, 5)#"
            name = "getFiles"
            filter = "#filters#" 
            recurse = "no"
            />
<cfoutput query="getFiles">
     <!---get the file name--->
     <cfset fname = ListFirst(getFiles.name, "." )>
     <!---get the file extenstion--->
     <cfset exten = ListLast(getFiles.name, ".")>
     <cfif getFiles.type eq "file" and getFiles.name neq "thumbs.db">
          <tr>
               <td align="absmiddle"><a href="#buildUrl('main.attachDownload?filename=#getFiles.name#')#">#fname#</a></td>
               <td align="absmiddle"><img src="/art/assets/images/fileTypes/#fileIcon#" title="#exten#"/></td>
               <td align="absmiddle">
                    <!---convert the file size from bytes into mb and kb--->
                    <cfif getFiles.size GT "1000000">
                         #numberformat(getFiles.size*.000001, 9.99)#Mb
                    <cfelse>
                         #numberformat(getFiles.size*.001, 9)#kb
                    </cfif>
               </td>
               <td align="absmiddle">#getFiles.dateLastModified#</td>
               <td align="absmiddle"><a href="#buildUrl('main.deleteFile?filename=#getFiles.name#')#" onClick="alert('Are you sure you want to delete this file?')"><img src="/art/assets/images/delete.png" title="delete file" /></a></td>
          </tr>
      </cfif> 
</cfoutput>    

    <!---display all directories and their files for admin--->
        <cfdirectory 
            action="list" 
            directory="#local.baseWebPath#" 
            name="allDirectories" 
            recurse="true"
            />
```

Diplaying the individual customer directory works well.  However, when the admin is logged in, all directories should be displayed as well as files grouped by customer.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: There are already file browsers for CF - have you investigated adapting an existing tool?

Comment: @PeterBoughton:  I am unaware.  Can you please enlighten me?

Comment: http://cffm.riaforge.org/
http://coldfusionfilemanager.riaforge.org/
http://www.bennadel.com/projects/kinky-file-explorer.htm
https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=coldfusion+file+browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Query of Queries to sort correctly

```
<cfquery name="getFiles" dbtype="query">
SELECT name, size, datelastmodified, directory
FROM getFiles
ORDER BY directory
</cfquery>
```

You can then use

```
<cfoutput query="getFiles" group="directory">
 #getFiles.directory# <!--- format to show only the custID --->
  <cfoutput>
   <!--- outupt table here --->
  </cfoutput>         
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Thanks Matt.  Building off your suggestion, I produced this:  http://pastebin.com/qb3RS9ts  it is a bit closer.  The directories are headings and the files are listed below them, but all files are listed, not the files associated with the directory.  What am I missing?

Comment: Actually, I'm building off the example in the CFWACK in chapter 61.  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: you have to use a group by and order by the value you're grouping by otherwise it doesn't group correctly